# ¿Como calcular promedio, aplicar regla de 3 y comparar porcentajes obtenidos dentro de bucles for?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo en una tabla almacenadas las calificaciones y número de inasistencias de tres periodos, de alumnos. Estos se mandaron mediante un arreglo mandando en el mismo la calificación y las inasistencias: parcial1[0]=calificacion,  parcial1[1]=inasistencia.
Ahora lo que intentaba era mandar desde un input un número de clases impartidas en el semestre, y en un arreglo de inputs se enviara el número de asistencias totales en el semestre de cada alumno capturadas.

Dentro de un ciclo calcular el promedio de esos 3 parciales (mandando las calificaciones mostradas desde la misma tabla donde son impresas) por alumno, después aplicar una regla de 3 dentro de otro ciclo que calculara el porcentaje de asistencias en base a las clases impartidas y el número de asistencias por cada alumno, enviados y recibidos en arreglo. Guardar ese porcentaje como número entero en otro campo de la tabla (asistencias).

Después compara ese valor del porcentaje obtenido y si es igual o mayor a 80 que se almacene el promedio calculado antes, de ser menor el promedio sea 5.
Los errores que genera son: 
`PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1707 in /home/platafo6/public_html/View/Docente/Capt_Calif.php on line 135`
`PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1707 in /home/platafo6/public_html/View/Docente/Capt_Calif.php on line 135`
Creo que es más problema de lógica... acomodar las variables correctamente y las llaves de los ciclos.

```js
<?php

  require_once '../../Model/Conexion.php';
  require_once '../../Model/Model_Docentes.php';

//$connect = conectar(); //conexion a la bd
  $conexion =  conectar();


//si esta puesto el boton de enviar,  si el array de los id grupos y el de idalumno no esta vacio
if ( isset($_POST['formAlumno']) && !empty($_POST['idgpo']) && !empty($_POST['idalumno']) ) {
      //recogirndo arrays 
     //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      $grupo      = $_POST['idgpo']; 
      $alumno     = $_POST['idalumno'];
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //CAPTURANDO PARCIAL 1
      if(isset($_POST['parcialP1']))  {

      $parcialP1  = $_POST['parcialP1'];

      $n = count($parcialP1);
      $num_alumno = 1;  //contador de registros de alumno en gpo
      
      for ($i=1; $i < $n; $i += 2, ++$num_alumno) {  //pre-incremento de 2  y bucle para primer parcial

           $p1        = $parcialP1[$i - 1]; //calificación
           $inasisP1  = $parcialP1[$i];     //numero inasistencias
          
            $gpo  = $grupo[$num_alumno - 1];
            $al   = $alumno[$num_alumno - 1];  
        
          //consulta update para colocar las caliicaciones e inasiatencias, where con valores de grupo y alumno
          $sql1 = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET parcial1 = '{$p1}', inasisP1 = '{$inasisP1}'
                 WHERE idAlumno = '{$al}' AND idGrupo = '{$gpo}'") or die (mysqli_error($conexion));
               if ($sql1) {
          ?>
            <script>
             alert('Calificaciones Capturadas Correctamente')
             location.href = "Grupos.php"; 
            </script>       
            <?php
          }
      
      }  //fin for P2
    } //FIN ISSET

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////CAPTURANDO PARCIAL 2
    if(isset($_POST['parcialP2']))  {

       $parcialP2  = $_POST['parcialP2'];

       $n2 = count($parcialP2);
       
       $num2_alumno = 1;  //contador de registros de alumno en gpo
      
       for ($i=1; $i < $n2; $i += 2, ++$num2_alumno) {

        $p2 = $parcialP2[$i - 1];
        $inasisP2 = $parcialP2[$i];
        
         $gpo  = $grupo[$num2_alumno - 1];
         $al   = $alumno[$num2_alumno - 1];   

          //consulta update para colocar las caliicaciones e inasiatencias, where con valores de grupo y alumno
          $sql2 = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET parcial2 = '{$p2}', inasisP2 = '{$inasisP2}'
                 WHERE idAlumno = '{$al}' AND idGrupo = '{$gpo}'") or die (mysqli_error($conexion));
          if ($sql2) {
          ?>
            <script>
             alert('Calificaciones Capturadas Correctamente')
             location.href = "Grupos.php"; 
            </script>       
            <?php
          }
      
      }  //fin for P2
    } //FIN ISSET

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// //CAPTURANDO PARCIAL 3
    if(isset($_POST['parcialP3']))  {

       $parcialP3  = $_POST['parcialP3'];

       $n3 = count($parcialP3);
       
       $num3_alumno = 1;  //contador de registros de alumno en gpo
      
       for ($i=1; $i < $n3; $i += 2, ++$num3_alumno) {

        $p3 = $parcialP3[$i - 1];
        $inasisP3 = $parcialP3[$i];

         $gpo  = $grupo[$num3_alumno - 1];
         $al   = $alumno[$num3_alumno - 1];           
    
             //consulta update para colocar las caliicaciones e inasiatencias, where con valores de grupo y alumno
          $sql3 = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET parcial3 = '{$p3}', inasisP3 = '{$inasisP3}'
                 WHERE idAlumno = '{$al}' AND idGrupo = '{$gpo}'") or die (mysqli_error($conexion));    

           if ($sql3) {
          ?>
            <script>
             alert('Calificaciones Capturadas Correctamente')
             location.href = "Grupos.php"; 
            </script>       
            <?php
          }
      
      }  //fin for P2
    } //FIN ISSET

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//CALCULO DE PROMEDIOS DE ALUMNO Y % DE ASISTENCIAS
if ( isset($_POST['numsesiones']) && isset($_POST['asistotales']) )  {

      $asistotales  = $_POST['asistotales']; //valores de arreglo recibido
      $numsesiones  = $_POST['numsesiones'];  //valor recibido de un input

         $parcial1  = $_POST['parcialP1']; //arreglo parcial1[] =[calif][inasis][calif][inasis]
         $parcial2  = $_POST['parcialP2']; //arreglo parcial2[] =[calif][inasis][calif][inasis]
         $parcial3  = $_POST['parcialP3']; //arreglo parcial3[] =[calif][inasis][calif][inasis]
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////     
      $tamaP1 = count($parcial1);
      $tamaP2 = count($parcial2);
      $tamaP3 = count($parcial3);

      $num_alumno1 = 1;
       for ($i1 = 1; $i1 < $tamaP1; $i1 += 2, ++$num_alumno1) {  //for calcula promedios por alumno
            $p1b = $parcial1[$i1 - 1]; //P1
            $idgpo  = $grupo[$num_alumno1 - 1]; //LINEAS DE ERROR
            $idalu   = $alumno[$num_alumno1 - 1]; //134
          
            $num_alumno2 = 1;
            for ($i2 = 1; $i2 < $tamaP2; $i2 += 2, ++$num_alumno2) {  //for calcula promedios por alumno
                 $p2b = $parcial2[$i2 - 1]; //P1
                 $idgpo  = $grupo[$num_alumno2 - 1];
                 $idalu   = $alumno[$num_alumno2 - 1];
               
                $num_alumno3 = 1;    
                 for ($i3 = 1; $i3 < $tamaP3; $i3 += 2, ++$num_alumno3) {  //for calcula promedios por alumno
                 $p3b = $parcial2[$i3 - 1]; //P1
                 $idgpo  = $grupo[$num_alumno3 - 1];
                 $idalu   = $alumno[$num_alumno3 - 1];

                  $sumab = $p1b+$p2b+$p3b;
                    $nb = 3;
                    $promediob = $sumab/3;
                                       
                       $promediob = round($promediob); //redondeando de .5 hacia abajo y .5 hacia arriba
  
                            $sql = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET final = '{$promediob}'
                                   WHERE idAlumno = '{$idalu}' AND idGrupo = '{$idgpo}'") or die (mysqli_error($conexion));
               }  //for p3
             } //for p2
           } //for p1

      $n4 = count($asistotales);  //cuenta elementos del array de asistencias 
        
      $num4_alumno = 1;  //contador de registros de alumno en gpo
      for ($i=0; $i < $n4; $i++, ++$num4_alumno) {
        //regla de 3
        $a = $asistotales[$i];
        $regla = $a * 100;
        $asis = $regla/$numsesiones;  //porcentaje de asistencia
        $asis = round($asis); //redondeamos de: .5 hacia abajo  de .5 hacia arriba el porcentaje de asistnecia

             $idgpo  = $grupo[$num4_alumno - 1]; //-1 porque el array recibe (calificacion,inasistencia)
             $idalu   = $alumno[$num4_alumno - 1]; //inicializa en 1 = inasistencia, -1 = calificacion    
                 //insertamos el porcentaje total de asistencia redondeado a entero
             $sqla = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET asistencias = '{$asis}'
                     WHERE idAlumno = '{$idalu}' AND idGrupo = '{$idgpo}'") or die (mysqli_error($conexion));

              //RESTRICCIONES DEL 80% DE ASISETENCIA
              if ($asis < 80) {           //DE SER MENOR DEL 80
                  $sqlb = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET final = 5
                  WHERE idAlumno = '{$idalu}' AND idGrupo = '{$idgpo}'") or die (mysqli_error($conexion));
              
                      } /*elseif ($asis >= 80) { //else DE SER IGUAL O MAYOR AL 80
                       
                          $sqlc = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET final = '{$promediob}'
                          WHERE idAlumno = '{$idalu}' AND idGrupo = '{$idgpo}'") or die (mysqli_error($conexion));
                          }*/                    
             } //fin for asistencias                           
      } //if empty && isset
////////////////////////  FINAL /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
} //fin if isset formAlumno, idgpo e idalumno 
     
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El siguiente error

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset

Hace referencia a que estas tratando de hacer alguna operacion con tu array utilizando un indice que no esta definido. Por un lado, te recomiendo que depures el codigo añadiendo un print_r de todos los valores que llegan por POST, de esta forma vas a identificar donde esta el error

```
echo "<pre>";
prin_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

Por otro lado, la metodologia mas conveniente siempre que trabajes con arrays de claves incrementales es que verifiques cada indice antes de realizar alguna operacion con el.
Por ejemplo supongamos que en el array $prueba no hay ningun indice definido.

El siguiente script arrojara la misma advertencia que estas viendo en tu programa

```
if (($prueba[0] * $prueba[1]) > 10){
    echo "Un mensaje de prueba";
}
```

En cambio, si verificaras el indice antes de utilizarlo (como en el siguiente ejemplo) no arrojaria ninguna advertencia.

```
if ((isset($prueba[0]) && isset($prueba[1])) && (!empty($prueba[0]) && !empty($prueba[1])) && ($prueba[0] * $prueba[1]) > 10){
    echo "Un mensaje de prueba";
}
```

En este ejemplo primero verifico que las claves que voy a utilizar tengan un valor definido usando la funcion isset. La segunda verificacion es para detectar si estas claves ademas de estar definidas tiene un valor no vacio o mayor a 0.

Comment: buen análisis, gracias